# Autosizing mask attaching the UIView to the bottom of the screen not the UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, autoresizingmask

I have a `UIScrollView` with 480 height, so on 3,5-inch iPhone the scroll is enabled to view the content because of the navigation bar. I have two `UIView` which should be in the bottom part of the `UIScrollView`. I try to solve this issue without the manual adjustments in the code and use only IB for this purposes. So, if I try to set for this `UIViews` the autosizing mask like this:

[image]

on 3,5-inch screen (small one) the `UIViews` are attaching to the bottom of the screen not to the bottom part of the `UIScrollView`.

The autosizing mask for the `UIScrollView` looks like this:

[image]

when I try to change the autosizing mask for the views to:

[image]

the problem is with 4-inch screen - the image is not attaching to the bottom of the page..

Any help?

Comment: can you share the left panel of your IB?

Comment: @iBug here https://www.dropbox.com/s/0usms62bqh37g2f/Screenshot%202014-05-20%2010.08.48.png

Comment: @ShurupuS share your views Outlet ,i.e the UIScrollView and UIViews.The middle part designing pat

Comment: @Jayaprada https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmer8lfeaus90ku/Screenshot%202014-05-20%2013.16.52.png

Comment: @ShurupuS,that image is not opening.Webpage  is not available

Comment: @Jayaprada http://www.imagebam.com/image/6b6a6c327649357 and this? I'm talking about the two buttons in the bottom part and the separator - they should appear in the bottom of the UIScrollView not the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the Bottom View at the bottom of the UIScrollView not self.View.Then

- Take a UIView(myView).Add UIScrollView and your bottomView (which you
  want to show at the bottom of the UIScrollview) to myView.Then Your auto resizing will work as expected.Refer below Image

[image]